# Websocket handshake Error between Node.js and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I'm writing a application using sockets, but can't seem to get the initial handshake to work. I'm using WebSockets + React on my front-end, running on PORT 8080, and Node.js socket on the backend running on PORT 5000.
The front-end handshake is done through my component like so:

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000', ['json']);
        this.socket.onerror = err => {
            console.log(err)
        }
        this.socket.onmessage = e => {
            let res = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(e, res);
            let copyArr = [...this.state.message]
            copyArr.push(res);

            this.setState({
                message: copyArr
            });
        }
    }
```

On my Node server, I do:

```
const server = http.createServer();

server.on('upgrade', (req, socket) => {

    if(req.headers['upgrade'] !== "websocket"){
        socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        return;
    }

    const acceptKey = req.headers['sec-websocket-key'];
    const acceptHash = generateValue(acceptKey);

    console.log('accepkey', acceptKey, 'hash', acceptHash);

    const resHeaders = [ 'HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake', 'Upgrade: WebSocket', 'Connection: Upgrade', `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${acceptHash}` ];

    console.log(resHeaders);

    let protocols = req.headers['sec-websocket-protocol'];
    protocols = !protocols ? [] : protocols.split(',').map(name => name.trim());

    if(protocols.includes('json')){
        console.log('json here');
        resHeaders.push(`Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: json`);
    }

    socket.write(resHeaders.join('\r\n') + '\r\n\r\n');
})

function generateValue(key){
    return crypto
      .createHash('sha1')
      .update(key + '258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', 'binary')
      .digest('base64');
}
```

When my React component mounts, it tries to establish the initial handshake but fails with the error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value`. I've checked using Chrome developer tool and found this 
[image]
While on the backend, when logging the request accept-key header, and response headers, I saw this:
[image]

So, unless I'm mistaken about these headers, it seems that the request and response accept-key header somehow changes when making it's way from the client to the server, and vice versa. How is this happening? Or have I misunderstood what's going on. Why exactly is the initial handshake not working?

Comment: In your screenshot you're looking not at your websocket request. Look at the URL, this is webpack-dev-server websocket connection (localhost:8080) which were successful (status code 101)

Answer (score 1):

There is a en dash `–` instead of hyphen `-` in `258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11` after `E914`
So replace it with hyphen `-`

reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-WebSocket-Accept

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `generateValue` function is wrong, you pass `binary` as the inputData encoding which is a keyword for `latin1` according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings). But I believe it is `UTF-8` string, not `latin1`, so the result hash is wrong. So just try to use `update(key + '258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', 'utf8')` or even without the second `utf8` argument since it is a default.